# Sync website calendar with phone calendar

Tags: android, iphone, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, synchronization

I am trying to sync phone calendar with website calendar. but no luck. I have tried following methods.

1. sync phone calendar with Google calendar.
2. Now trying to fetch events from Google calendar that later will show on my website.
3. To fetch events from Google calendar, i need calendar id.
4. To fetch calendar id i am using Google calendar v3 API
5. but problem is without user authentication or user log in i am not able to get user calendar id or events
6. so my first question is can i get user calendar id without user log in?
7. My second question, is there any other alternative for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Calendar id is the email of the calendar.
However, you cannot access user data unless you are authenticated and authorized to do so. You will either need:

1. the calendar to be public
2. or you will need an Oauth2 token for the accessed calendar (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)
3. or the calendar will need to be shared to you or your service account (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)
4. or the domain settings will have to allow you to access that calendar (https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation).